# xCode 9.0 beta (9M136h) run on device: Failed to find a suitable device for the type IBSimDeviceTypeiPad2x

Tags: xcode9

When I tried to run out app in device with Xcode 9.0 beta (9M136h), I got the following errors.

```
/xxxx/Assets.xcassets: Failed to find a suitable device for the type
IBSimDeviceTypeiPad2x (com.apple.dt.Xcode.IBSimDeviceType.iPad-2x) with runtime iOS
11.0 (11.0 - 15A5278f) - com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimRuntime.iOS-11-0
```

Does there any suggestion for this issue?

Answer (score 0):

I just uninstalled the app that was on the phone (maybe from a previous beta) and then it worked fine.